# Create tasks to other gmail acount using google task api

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, accountmanager, google-tasks-api

I am using google task  api, it works fine with my account associated  to my device, but I can create tasks ONLY on this account, so how can I create tasks for other Gmail accounts that I know the login and password using my  configured device account ?

For example my current account is MyAcount@gmail.com it is the account associated with the tablet, I want to create a task for YourAcount@gmail.com that I know the password.

to get token I'am using the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(....) and GoogleAcountManager

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use username/password authentication to access the tasks api. The only thing you can do is login to that user, then use the Oauth Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to generate a refresh token, which you can embed in your app to request an access token, which you can then use to access the API.

NB, this is all a really bad idea.

Comment: Thxs for replaying, but can you give me and example using Java code in Android, because I am using the Java client API and google play authentification service, and I didnt' find how refresh Token using an other account

Comment: You'll need to explain your requirement in a lot more detail. Remember I did say it's a really bad idea.